# How can i show final price on product page?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-page

I want to show price accroding to selected attribute option of configurable product.
[image: Refer Image Here]

Comment: you dont need to write code for this just open you configurable product and you can see all the simple product with different attributes you can open these products one by one and can set price for them.

Comment: I want to display price of configurable product accordingly case price attibute. Just like the image show above.

Comment: Thanks it work but price show after review section and i want it after case price.

Comment: i really didn't get it, could you please share a little bit of more detail

Comment: I want to show  price after case Price Attribute same as show in image that i post. But price is show after review section on product info main block. 
Screenshot:- 
https://prnt.sc/t8eko0

Comment: i got it please check my ans

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code which will return the HTML of price element and on change of custom options price will change.

```
$abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');
echo $abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($product);
```

Use this in your phtml file and style accordingly if necessary.

Comment: In which phtml file?

Comment: is this is a default Magento product view page or your custom created?

Comment: I use custom theme where i use luma as a parent theme.

Comment: As per @Pramod comment, you don't have to write additional code. check your console for any js errors. and also confirm that price-box.js is loading or not.

Answer (score 0):

create a file with name `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` in your theme at `/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/`

and add these lines of codes in it :-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.addtocart.additional" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

now run `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:Deploy -f`.
`flush cache` and ur done

Comment: Thank You, but its not what i actually want it move whole top section on buttom i only want price before quantity and after drpdown option.
 https://prnt.sc/t8h4rm

Comment: yeah but only im case of configurable product

Comment: So there is any way to do this?